# ClearML server IP address not used with localhost and SSH port forwarding

Tags: devops, local, portforwarding, trains, clearml

Trying to use clearml-server on own Ubuntu 18.04.5.

I use env variables to set the IP Address of my clearml-server.

```
export CLEARML_HOST_IP=127.0.0.1
export TRAINS_HOST_IP=127.0.0.1
```

But it still is available thorugh the external server IP.
How can I deactivate the listeners for external IP in clearml-server config?

Edit:
According to this:
I use SSH Port forward to access local instance from my computer outside of the network. But I can't access custom uploaded images (task-> debug samples) as they will not use my port forwarded URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a ClearML (Trains) team member

Basically the docker-compose will expose only the API/Web/File server , you can further limit the exposure to your localhost only, by changing the following section in your ClearML server [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/allegroai/clearml-server/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml)

```yaml
networks:
  backend:
    driver:
      bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: "127.0.0.1"
  frontend:
    driver: 
      bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: "127.0.0.1"
```

Based on docker's [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/)